# Proper syntax for ASP.NET hyperlink

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am trying to send an ASIN number into the querystring from a hyperlink and I'm having trouble getting the correct syntax.  Any ideas?

```
<asp:HyperLink ID="hlProductPage" Enabled="true" runat="server" NavigateUrl="ProductPage.aspx?ASIN=<%# Eval("ASIN")%>">Read More...</asp:HyperLink>
```

Thanks so much!

Answer (score 7):

```
NavigateUrl='<%# Eval("ASIN", "ProductPage.aspx?ASIN={0}")%>'
```

When you use `<% %>` in attributes of **server/user controls** `<%` must appear just after the opening quote and `%>` must appear just before the closing quote. In other words, you cannot have both code and static content. Also, use single quotes, that way you can use double quotes for strings without confusing the parser.

Answer (score 1):

try

```
NavigateUrl='ProductPage.aspx?ASIN=<%# Eval("ASIN")%>'>
```

notice the single quotes

Answer (score -1):

You'll need to set the NavigateURL property in the code behind.